# Awk adding constant values

Tags: shell, awk, solaris

I have data in the text file like val1,val2 with multiple lines
and I want to change it to 1,val1,val2,0,0,1

I tried with print statement in awk(solaris) to add constants by it didn't work.

What is the correct way to do it ?

---

(From the comments) This is what I tried

```
awk -F, '{print "%s","1,"$1","$2"0,0,1"}' test.txt
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Maybe you were nearly there.

Comment: awk -F, '{print "%s","1,"$1","$2"0,0,1"}' test.txt

Comment: @TejasJoshi Try removing `"%s",`

Comment: please edit your question to include your sample code. Otherwise we'll get a long discussion running in comments of information that should be in the main body of the question. Good luck.

Comment: There are multiple awk version on Solaris. Unfortunately the default one is /usr/bin/awk and that is old, broken awk which must never be used so that will be causing you problems if you are trying to use it. Use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead on Solaris (or, even better, install gawk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the command you posted, a little change makes it:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print 1,$1,$2,0,0,1}' file
1,val1,val2,0,0,1
```

OR using `printf` (I prefer `print`):

```
$ awk -F, '{printf "1,%s,%s,0,0,1", $1, $2}' file
1,val1,val2,0,0,1
```

Answer (score 2):

To prepend every line with the constant `1` and append with `0,0,1` simply do:

```
$ awk '{print 1,$0,0,0,1}' OFS=, file
1,val1,val2,0,0,1
```

A idiomatic way would be:

```
$ awk '$0="1,"$0",0,0,1"' file
1,val1,val2,0,0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*/1,&,0,0,1/' inputfile
```

Example:

```
$ echo val1,val2 | sed 's/.*/1,&,0,0,1/'
1,val1,val2,0,0,1
```